# Create python string from object values

Tags: python, string

I don't know the best way to describe what I am really looking for
probably this example is the best for explaining my problem:

I have the following list of strings (my object names):

```
mynames = ["A","B","C"]
```

my objects itself are defined as:

```
A = "Hello"
B = 12
C = "This is C"
```

Now I'd like to create a comma-separated string with all values of the objects mentioned
in "mynames" like:

```
myresult = "Hallo,12,This is C"
```

of course I could do it manually like:

```
",".join([A,str(B),C])
```

but is there a way to create the result based on the list "mynames", something like ",".join(mynames)??

thanks,

/j

Comment: How about mynames list storing the objects instead of strings?, is there any reason for it?

Comment: Don't do that. Instead, make `mynames` a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in other answers, you can use eval, literal-eval, globals, locals, or other such nonsense to complete your task - but your approach is wrong.

as i think is mentioned in other answers, you are better off using a different data structure, a dictionary perhaps. for instance, in your example:

```
A = "Hello"
B = 12
C = "This is C"
```

can be done with:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict["A"] = "Hello"
my_dict["B"] = 12
my_dict["C"] = "This is C"
```

and then you can simply do this:

```
mynames = ["A","B","C"]
print [my_dict[key] for key in mynames]
```

on the console, this is the result:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> my_dict["A"] = "Hello"
>>> my_dict["B"] = 12
>>> my_dict["C"] = "This is C"
>>> mynames = ["A","B","C"]
>>> print [my_dict[key] for key in mynames]
['Hello', 12, 'This is C']
```

making them into one string is simple now, and im sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly of course. I have to focus more on the usage of dictionaries... :)

Comment: dictionaries are great. and there are many more types of data structures, each with their own ideal uses. dicts however, are a great backbone. when dealing with many different variables that are all related - a dict is almost a must. and since python doesnt care much for types, your dictionary can of course, contain anything, even more dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer is to use globals() or locals() as in

```
lst = [globals()[x] for x in 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

and the correct one is

```
 don't do that
```

Every time you attempt to manipulate variable names in python you're doing a wrong thing. Use an appropriate data structure, like dict.

Comment: SO should change the syntax highlighting for some important messages, such as `don't do that`

Comment: I believe there is a way to indicate the language for syntax highlighting -- some sort of funky comment -- but I can't remember it.

Comment: @katrielalex: [<!-- language: none -->](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is your friend here:

```
",".join([ str(eval(e)) for e in mynames ])
```